# iPhone - accessing a NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, json, nsdictionary

I have a JSON String which I transform to a NSDictionary, and the I get the values for the key "people" to a NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *testDict = [jsonString JSONValue];
NSDictionary *peopleDict = [testDict objectForKey:@"people"];
```

A NSLog of peopleDict

```
NSLog(@"%@", peopleDict);
```

return me the following:

```
{
0 =     {
    id = 1;
    name = Doe;
    date = "Fri Dec 04 13:50:30 +0200 2009";
};
1 =     {
    id = 20;
    name = Mr. T;
    date = "Fri Nov 18 17:55:30 +0200 2009";
};
2 =     {
    id = 100;
    name = TestName;
    date = "Mon Nov 30 12:00:10 +0200 2009";
};
}
```

The number of results, I know (in this case 3).
But how could I access the rows 0..2 and the key-values?
id is an int value, name a String, and date also a String.

Does anyone know?

Thanks a lot in advance & Best Regards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (id key in peopleDict) {
  NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [peopleDict objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Here's a [link to NSDictionary reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

you may want to take a look to: *Accessing Keys and Values* methods:

- allKeys
- allKeysForObject:
- allValues
- getObjects:andKeys:
- objectForKey:
- objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:
- valueForKey: